# How to extract metadata from tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm loading [this](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/metadata/2) object detection model in python. I can load it with the following lines of code:

```py
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite

model_path = 'path_to_model_file.tf'
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path)
```

I'm able to perform inferences on this without any problem. However, labels are suposed to be included in the metadata, according to [model's documentation](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/metadata/2), but I can't extract it.

The closest I was, it was when following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#visualize_the_metadata):

```py
from tflite_support import metadata as _metadata

displayer = _metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(model_path)
export_json_file = "extracted_metadata.json")
json_file = displayer.get_metadata_json()

# Optional: write out the metadata as a json file
with open(export_json_file, "w") as f:
  f.write(json_file)
```

but the very first line of code, fails with this error: `{AtributeError}'int' object has no attribute 'tobytes'`.

How to extract it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about the label file, you can simply run command like `unzip model_path` on Linux or Mac. TFLite model with metadata is essentially a zip file. See the [public introduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#model_with_metadata_format) for more details.

You code snippet to extract metadata works on my end. Make sure to double check `model_path`. It should be a string, such as `"lite-model_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1_metadata_2.tflite"`.

If you'd like to read label files in an Android app, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/630bd990cc909cee217a805e4b4ce258721f3432/lite/examples/object_detection/android/lib_interpreter/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java#L121-L132) is the sample code to do so.

Comment: Tried again my code and"worked": I can now see the metadata but it doesn't show the labels file itself. However, the unzip worked, thanks!

Comment: MetadataDisplayer does not show the labels, through we should have to. I'll add a method to do so.